# What is the equivalent ElasticSearch query for this SQL

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I have many documents with a unique reference, but some may share the same hash.

This sql query returns one row per unique hash.

```
select hash, min(reference)
from moo
group by hash
```

As reference is a string I cant use the min aggregation in ElasticSearch.

I have been able to accomplish this with the following ElasticSearch query...

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {    
        "items": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "doc.hash"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "id": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "doc.reference",
                        "size": 1
                    }
                }                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**I was wondering if there was a "better" way?**

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "items": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "doc.hash",
                "size": 5000
            },
            "aggs": {
                "reference": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have this as an alternative, I just feel the response from elasticsearch is so verbose.

i.e for each "hash" i get all of this as a result

```
{
    "key": "c8964350989772cc4348e72d217b89b8",
    "doc_count": 17,
    "reference": {
        "hits": {
            "total": 17,
            "max_score": null,
            "hits": [
                {
                    "_index": "default",
                    "_type": "blah",
                    "_id": "e412c76b-b767-4c96-8cd6-ef8d6bf90acd",
                    "_score": null,
                    "_source": {
                        "meta": {
                            "rev": "1-00048ac556524b730000000002000001",
                            "flags": 33554433,
                            "expiration": 0,
                            "id": "e412c76b-b767-4c96-8cd6-ef8d6bf90acd"
                        }
                    },
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

when all i really want is two values, the hash and the ...

"key": "c8964350989772cc4348e72d217b89b8", "id": "e412c76b-b767-4c96-8cd6-ef8d6bf90acd"

Was wondering if there was a way to ease the load on the server to generate all the extra fluff, and if there was a cleaner way to do that type of query.

Comment: does the above es query  return the `min (doc.reference)`  , doesn't look to me it would ?

Comment: I dont really care about the min(doc.reference) i just want one per hash.

Comment: FWIW if you want `min` you could use [top_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html)

Comment: Ive added the top_hits version and a comment about it, would appreciate your input.

Comment: you could use [source-filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html) in top hits to get the fields you want in response. Also if you want `min` in top hits i would add a sort block and sort on `reference`. This would depend on how `reference` is mapped if i.e `not_analyzed`. A `sample document` in the post would help understand better , the document shown in response doesn't seem to have `hash` or `reference` fields